# What can cause a 'thump' sound in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been hearing a thump in Minecraft survival mode whenever I play alone or with my friends.

The thump appears to happen randomly, and it isn't because of the headphones I'm wearing.

What can cause this?

Comment: You might want to add more detail. Does it happen in a certain ares (near your base, down in a cave in a particular spot?) And what sort of thump does it sound like? the sound of a mob hitting the ground? Something else?

Comment: Go into the sound settings and turn off different types of sound (animals, footsteps, hostile mobs etc). Turn one off, then play for a bit, then turn off another etc. That'll help you narrow down the source. My guess is probaby a cow, llama or similarly-sized mob taking a step, or even an idle cave noise.

Comment: I would recommend that you provide a link to a video with a time stamp to the sound effect, or going to the minecraft wiki and finding the sound effect there. It's very difficult to recognize a sound effect if we don't know what it sounds like nor what causes it. The player alone has at least 15 different thumps so it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

### What *can* cause a 'thump' sound? Pretty much anything, depending on the type of 'thump' you mean.

As to what is specifically causing the noise you are hearing randomly? That is also entirely dependent on where you are and what's around you. It could be a zombie falling to its death in a cave, or an Enderman placing a block of wood it picked up from the nearby forest.

If you want to identify what is causing the sound(s), you can use [Subtitles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Subtitles#History) to see what might be causing it. When you hear the sound, check to see if it showed up in the subtitles, and maybe check what other sounds might be connected to it.

Alternatively, you can use the [`/playsound`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/playsound) command, to try and narrow down what you think it might be, in case the Subtitles don't show it, or if you think you might have an idea of what it might be.